# MacBook Pro Trackpad popped

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro - admittedly this was ageing but still working OK, although it was warning about the battery.

I last used it a few days ago, and just noticed the lid was open which seemed to be because the trackpad had popped up.

The battery was obviously dead, but I managed to boot with a mouse.
The Apple store says they don't have replacement batteries for this model.

I was planning to take the MacBook Pro with me on a trip in a couple of weeks.

What is the best course of action. I rarely need to use on battery, but this model is a lot more portable than my iMac.

---------- Edit
I eventually managed to remove the battery. The Loctite on the screws defeated my normal #00 screwdriver so I purchased a new (expensive) set, which after the application of percussion techniques was able to remove the screws, and the battery is now out. In the meantime the bulging trackpad is now cracked.

With the exception of extracting the screws the removal process was quite simple.

ifixit referred me to their Australian store, which did not have replacement batteries, and informed me the US store is unable to ship batteries internationally.

I will pursue other options; possibly deferring purchase until a future visit to the US. (I mainly use the MacBook when travelling.)

I have a subsidiary question - the battery had a warning NOT to remove; it is possible/safe to operate without a battery?

Comment: Do you mean that the Apple store doesn't have replacements for the battery or the trackpad? I'm sure there are still lots of 3rd party battery replacements for 2011 MBP.

Comment: Replace the battery. They're cheap, easily sourced ([Amazon](https://amzn.to/2N8LK5P), [eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=macbook+pro+2011+battery)) and some of the easiest to change (not glued in like newer models).  After you remove the back cover, only one screw holds it in place.  Just be careful when removing the connector - pull *gently*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still happy with the performance of your macbook pro, I would recommend replacing the battery and the trackpad (in case it was bent when it popped). The replacement parts are fairly cheap and easy to install.

Ifixit has repair guides and parts available and are quite a reputable supplier of non-oem replacement parts: (the links are for the 13" model)

battery replacement: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Battery+Replacement/5116

trackpad replacement: https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009--Mid-2012-Trackpad/IF163-025-1

p.s. I have no affiliation with ifixt or the links provided above, I simply have happily used their services to fix an aging macbook pro (2010) in the past.